# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createInvite')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever I try and make an invite to one of my guild's channels, it doesn't work.

```
const {
  Client
} = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [] });

client.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`Bot ${client.user.username} is ready`);
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.first()
  await guild.channels.cache
        .filter(channel => channel.type === "text")
        .first()
        .createInvite()
        .then((invite) => console.log('Server: ' + invite.code))
})


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I get the title error and I don't understand why it wont work as I'm getting a channel and I'm creating an invite. Thanks

Comment: The error means that the call to `.first()` is returning `undefined`

Comment: Check the continents of client.guilds.cache.first() it might be null also it is possible that the filter can not file channel.type value.

Comment: @Mehrwarz _"it might be null"_ - The error is quite clear about the return value, and it's not `null` ;)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fixed my own question:

```
const {
  Client
} = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [] });

client.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`Bot ${client.user.username} is ready`);
  try {
    var channel = await client.channels.fetch('1056353927471308802');
    var invite = await channel.createInvite()
    console.log(`https://discord.gg/${invite.code}`)
  } catch {
    throw new Error(`Channel with ID ${sendChannel} not found`);
  }
})


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: Questions with a block of code and no description aren't really helpful. Please add a description explaining what the issue was in the first place and how you fixed it. This way, others that may find your question/answer in the future will be able to know exactly what the problem is and what's being changed without having to compare this code with the one in the question, which is just a waste of their time.

Comment: It doesn't answer your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The error likely lies in you filtering the guild's channels. `text` is not a valid channel type.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType

Check the `ChannelType` documentation for your corresponding discord.js version.