# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createInvite') || Discord.JS V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('servers')
    .setDescription('List all servers the bot is currently joined in.'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    // Fetch all guilds the bot is in
    const guilds = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch();
    // Initialize the flag variable to false
    let actionCompleted = false;

    // Build the initial embed with a dropdown menu
    const dropdown = guilds.map(guild => ({
      label: guild.name,
      value: guild.id,
    }));
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle('Bot Servers')
      .setDescription('Select a server to manage:')
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Servers:', value: 'Choose a server from the dropdown menu.', inline: true }
      )
      //.addField('\u200B', '\u200B')
      //.addField('\u200B', '\u200B');

    const menu = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId('server-select')
        .setPlaceholder('Select a Server')
        .setOptions(dropdown)
    
    const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
      .addComponents(menu)

    // Send the initial message with the dropdown menu
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [actionRow], ephemeral: true });

    // Wait for the user to select a server
    const filter = i => i.isSelectMenu() && i.customId === 'server-select' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 30000 });
    collector.on('collect', async i => {
      // Get the selected server
      const guild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch(i.values[0]);

      // Build the message with the server actions
      const actionsEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`${guild.name} Actions`)
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setDescription(`Choose an action for ${guild.name}:`)
        //.addField('\u200B', '\u200B')
        .addFields(
          { name: `1️⃣ Kick`, value: `Kick the bot from this server.`, inline: true },
          { name: `2️⃣ Invite`, value: `Invite yourself to this server.`, inline: true }
        )

      // Send the message with the action buttons
      const actionRow2 = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
          new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('kick-button')
            .setLabel('1️⃣ Kick')
            .setStyle('Danger'),
          new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('invite-button')
            .setLabel('2️⃣ Invite')
            .setStyle('Primary'),
        );
      await i.update({ embeds: [actionsEmbed], components: [actionRow2] });

      // Wait for the user to choose an action
      const filter2 = j => j.isButton() && j.message.id === i.message.id && j.user.id === interaction.user.id;
      const collector2 = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filter2, time: 30000 });
      collector2.on('collect', async j => {
        if (j.customId === 'kick-button') {
          // Ask the user to confirm they want to kick the bot
          const confirmEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`${guild.name} Kick Confirmation`)
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setDescription(`Are you sure you want to kick the bot from ${guild.name}?`)
            //.addField('\u200B', '\u200B')

            const confirmRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
              new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('confirm-kick-button')
                .setLabel('Yes')
                .setStyle('Danger'),
              new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('cancel-kick-button')
                .setLabel('No')
                .setStyle('Secondary'),
            );
          await j.update({ embeds: [confirmEmbed], components: [confirmRow] });

          // Wait for the user to confirm or cancel the kick
          const filter3 = k => k.isButton() && k.message.id === j.message.id && k.user.id === interaction.user.id;
          const collector3 = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filter3, time: 30000 });
          collector3.on('collect', async k => {
            if (k.customId === 'confirm-kick-button') {
              // Kick the bot from the selected server
              await guild.leave();
              const successEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle('Success!')
                .setColor('#00ff00')
                .setDescription(`The bot has been kicked from ${guild.name}.`);
              await k.update({ embeds: [successEmbed], components: [] });
              // Set the flag variable to true to indicate that the action has been cancelled
              actionCompleted = true;
            } else {
              // User cancelled the kick
              const cancelledEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle('Action Cancelled')
                .setColor('#ffff00')
                .setDescription('The kick action has been cancelled.');
              await k.update({ embeds: [cancelledEmbed], components: [] });
              // Set the flag variable to true to indicate that the action has been cancelled
              actionCompleted = true;
            }
            //collector2.stop();
            //collector.stop();
          });
        } else if (j.customId === 'invite-button') {
          try {
            // Generate a one-time use invite for the selected server
            const defaultChannel = guild.defaultChannel;
            const invite = await defaultChannel.createInvite({ maxUses: 1, unique: true , maxAge: 18000 });
            const successEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
              .setTitle('Success!')
              .setColor('#00ff00')
              .setDescription(`An invite has been created for ${guild.name}.`);
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
              .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setLabel('Invite Link')
                  .setStyle('Link')
                  .setURL(invite.url)
              ) 
            await j.update({ embeds: [successEmbed], components: [row] });
            actionCompleted = true;
          } catch (error) {
            const errorEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle('❌ ¦ Error!')
                .setColor('#ff0000')
                .setDescription('Something went wrong!')
                .addFields(
                  { name: '️ ¦ Error Comment', value: 'Invalid Invite!', inline: false },
                  { name: ' ¦ Recommended Advice', value: 'Reload the Bot/Command. Then, try again.', inline: false }
                )
            await j.reply({ embeds: [errorEmbed], ephemeral: true });
            actionCompleted = true;
          }
        }        
      });

      // Timeout if user doesn't choose an action
      collector2.on('end', async () => {
        // Check if the action has been completed or cancelled
        if (!actionCompleted) {
          // Display the timeout command
          const timeoutEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Timeout')
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setDescription('You did not select a server in time.');
          await i.editReply({ embeds: [timeoutEmbed], components: [] });
        }
      });
    });

      // Timeout if user doesn't choose an action
      collector.on('end', async () => {
        // Check if the action has been completed or cancelled
        if (!actionCompleted) {
          // Display the timeout command
          const timeoutEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Timeout')
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setDescription('You did not select a server in time.');
          await i.editReply({ embeds: [timeoutEmbed], components: [] });
        }
      });
  },
};
```

The problem is that I try to create an invite [Uses: 1-Use, Duration: 18000MilSec, Unique: True] to a specific server [Channel: Default Channel] that I have selected. But every time I select a Server and try to create an invite it returns this on the terminal:

```
C:\---\---\---\Commands\Developer\*commandname*.js:x
            const invite = await defaultChannel.createInvite({ maxUses: 1, unique: true , maxAge: 18000 });
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createInvite')
```

### NOTE:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74984787/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-createinvite) article does NOT seem to solve my case.

Comment: `defaultChannel` is `undefined`... `guild` does not seem to contain a value for that.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, you are correct. But, how can I fix that? I already used this type of code before and it worked fine `const defaultChannel = guild.systemChannel;`.

Comment: So, if that code worked, why are you not using it here?

Comment: Because it was a `guildCreate` Event and this code is a command. And also, it is about a completely different topic.

Comment: Is `guild` a valid variable? I see `guilds` defined at the top

Comment: Yes, it is. I have used it multiple times in the code in order to process some other information and tasks.

Comment: It might be relevant to see how you're getting `guild`?

Comment: Apparently `Guild` does not have a `defaultChannel`, [according to the docs](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.11.0/class/Guild)